# After rescheduling a partially completed task again, work progress is delayed. How do I update it in Microsoft Project?

Tags: tracking

A task has completed. It's, say, 20% of duration progress, but it is still behind the schedule. Then in tracking, the 20% completion was updated and the task was rescheduled to the current date or status date. After rescheduling the task, still its actual start date (second part of work) differs (late) from the rescheduled date. How can this be updated in the Microsoft Project?

Comment: I have re-read this question several times and I don't understand this: "After rescheduling the task still its actual start date (second part of work) differs (late) from the rescheduled date." Can you restate this more clearly or give a worked example?

Comment: This question needs some clarification and editing TLC, but appears to be on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Split the task on the [Gantt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) view. Leave the completed work where it was, and move the unfinished part to the new date.